# tensorflow mnist example accuracy does not increase

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I'm following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/dandelionmane/4f02ab8f1451e276fea1f165a20336f1#file-mnist-py) to learn tensorflow and tensorboard. Below are my code. The accuracy is stuck around random. I couldn't find out where is wrong.

Can someone point out where the bug is? I would also like to know how one should debug in tensorflow. Thanks.

---

#### import

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data  
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)  
import tensorflow as tf
```

#### define conv layer

```
def conv_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="conv"):  
    with tf.name_scope(name):  
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
        conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")
        act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return tf.nn.max_pool(act, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
```

#### define fc layer

```
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
        act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return act
```

#### define model

```
def mnist_model(learning_rate, path):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    sess = tf.Session()

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x")
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])
    tf.summary.image('input', x_image, 3)
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="labels")

    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
    conv_out = conv_layer(conv1, 32, 64, "conv2")

    flattened = tf.reshape(conv_out, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

    fc1 = fc_layer(flattened, 7 * 7 * 64, 1024, "fc1")
    logits = fc_layer(fc1, 1024, 10, "fc2")

    with tf.name_scope("xent"):
        xent = tf.reduce_mean(
            tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
                logits=logits, labels=y), name="xent")
        tf.summary.scalar("xent", xent)

    with tf.name_scope("train"):
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(xent)

    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
        accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
        tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

    summ = tf.summary.merge_all()

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(path)
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)


    for i in range(2000):
        batch = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        if i % 50 == 0:
            [train_accuracy, s] = sess.run([accuracy, summ], feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
            print train_accuracy
            writer.add_summary(s, i)
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch[0], y: batch[1]})
```

#### run

```
mnist_model(1e-3, path = "/tmp/mnist_demo/10")
```

#### output

```
0.09
0.08
0.04
0.07
0.12
0.12
0.09
0.12
0.08
0.1
0.11
0.14
0.11
0.11
0.13
0.11
0.19
0.06
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you apply relu activation on the last layer, so all the logits are thresholded at zero.

Solution:

change

```
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc"):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
        act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return act
```

to

```
def fc_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="fc", activation=tf.nn.relu):
    with tf.name_scope(name):
        w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1), name="W")
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]), name="B")
        act = tf.matmul(input, w) + b
        if activation is not None:
            act = activation(act)
        tf.summary.histogram("weights", w)
        tf.summary.histogram("biases", b)
        tf.summary.histogram("activations", act)
        return act
```

And pass None as activation in the last fully-connected layer:

```
logits = fc_layer(fc1, 1024, 10, "fc2", activation=None)
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you also have some advice on how to debug in tensorflow?

Comment: Well, afaik there is no general solution. Tensorflow 1.0 has a debugger, but I have not played with it yet. A good choice is to print out (in textual or graphical form) as much information as you can (e.g. gradients, activations, weights) and try to figure out where the mistake is. This helps to find the solution in most cases. Examining the graph (in tensorboard) helps as well.